# Hide a ProgressDialog over Firebase on a device without internet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this scenario:

- Show a progress dialog.
- Call to Firebase.
- When the data is got Hide the progress dialog

Works perfectly, but the the problem comes when the device does not have an Internet connection, in this case the progress Dialog is always exhibited, what I would like to do when the device does not have Internet is close the Progress and show an error message.

This is my code:

```
showProgessDialog();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("hello");
        DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");

        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    Log.d(Constans.LOG,"1.- datachange connected");
                    hideProgressDialog();
                } else {
                    Log.d(Constans.LOG,"2.- datachange disconnected");
                    showProgessDialog();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.err.println("3.- datachange cancelled");
            }
        });

        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(Constans.LOG,"4.- myRef addListenerForSingleValueEvent onDataChange");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(Constans.LOG,"5.- myRef addListenerForSingleValueEvent cancell");
            }
        });


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(Constans.LOG,"6.- myRef addValueEventListener onDataChange");
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mAboutMe.setText(value);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(Constans.LOG,"7.- myRef addValueEventListener error"+error.getDetails());

            }
        });
```

As you can see all the methods called have a number in the Log line, when the device has internet the methods calls order are :

> 2,1,6,4

When there is not internet is just called

> 2

I can not close the progress where I open it.

Any idea about what I can do it using the Firebase framework?

Comment: Using the debug tool: it never enter on `connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()`  when you lose internet? As google says, it is correct https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?hl=es

Comment: The problem is when the device does not have Internet when the app is launched

Answer (score 1):

You can check internet connection of device by using isConnected method of this class. Then you dismiss progress dialog when there is not internet connection

```
public class InternetConnectionDetector
{
   private Context context;

   public InternetConnectionDetector(Context context)
   {
       this.context = context;
   }

   public boolean isConnected()
   {
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

       //There are changes after apk lollipop while detecting internet connection:
       //if user's os newer then lollipop:
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
       {
           Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
           NetworkInfo networkInfo;

           for(Network mNetwork : networks)
           {
               networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(mNetwork);

               if(networkInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }

       //if user's os older then lollipop:
       else
       {
           //getAllNetworkInfo method work for only before API 19:
           NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();

           if(info != null)
           {
               for(NetworkInfo anInfo : info)
               {
                   if(anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                   {
                       return true;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @onur, I am wondering if I can do it using just Firebase library itself