# How to Detect Connectivity status from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show an alert in my app while the device is not connected to Internet.

The problem is that the firebase returns the connectedStatus as `false` by default during the application startup. Then the alert is called automatically during startup.

I found a workaround by adding another Boolean `hasConnected`. But it doesn't show alert, if the device is offline for the start!

How can i Fix this ?

**CODE**

```
private DatabaseReference connectedRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(".info/connected");
Boolean connectedStatus = true, hasConnected = false;

Boolean checkConnectedStatus() {
        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                connectedStatus = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connectedStatus) {
                    Timber.e("connected");
                } else {
                    Timber.e("not connected");
                    getView().showError(connectedStatus);
                }
                 if(hasConnected && !connectedStatus)
                    getView().showError(connectedStatus);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.err.println("Listener was cancelled at .info/connected");
            }
        });
        return connectedStatus;
    }
```

Comment: basically whenever `onDataChange()` is called, Firebase is connected. If it is not connected then `onCancelled()` will be the one that executed. And the flow of your code is wrong. (to make it simple, I'll explain more if needed) you should move whatever you want to do on `return` into inside `onDataChange()` and/or `onCancelled()`

Comment: @koceeng onDataChange is called even when there is no connection because I have enabled `setPersistenceEnabled`

Comment: The `.info/connected` node signals connectivity to the Firebase Database back-end. It does not signal internet connectivity. For that, use Android's `ConnectivityManager`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740206/hide-a-progressdialog-over-firebase-on-a-device-without-internet

Comment: Another reason your current code won't work is that the connection status is detected and changed asynchronously. This is a very common source of confusion. I recommend reading answers from this list top-down: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bandroid%5d%20asynchronous